# Unable to boot- please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU- error

Tags: linux-kernel, kali-linux

When i am installing Kali Linux using .iso image on my laptop, I am geting a black screen with an error: `Unable to boot- please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU`.

Any help??

[image: Unable to boot]

Answer (score 2):

Well, the answer is in the error message.

You are trying to install an [X86 (64bit) version on to a 32bit system](https://superuser.com/a/238131/669131). You need to use the `kali-linux-2016.2-i386.iso` installer.

Which can be found **[here](https://www.kali.org/downloads/)**.

Comment: Thanks for the support..    But I am using 64 bit system only..

Comment: @meenal Install a 32-bit OS and check the CPU info.